# Could not pre-launch appium and app doesn't get installed in iphone real device using appium

Tags: ios, appium, inspector

1. I am using appium version 1.3.7.
2. I have connected physical device via usb.
3. I have launched appium server,after a while appium get crashed.
4. I have pasted that full log below.
5. I have attached the screen shot below.

[image]

```
Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --pre-launch --platform-version "8.1" --platform-name "iOS" --app "/Users/al/work/sample.app" --udid "f5de3fd5ccded92e40e86c652ce2a6f9414fe1a0" --device-name "iPhone 4s"

info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode

info: Pre-launching app

info: [debug] Using local app from command line: /Users//al/work/sample.app
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 1cdc5dc0-36d2-40b9-922b-33601f28846b

info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1

info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate

info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)

info: [debug] Parsed app Localizable.strings
info: [debug] Getting bundle ID from app

info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)

info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/alk/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
...
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/alk/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js

info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/alk/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 4s","platformVersion":"8.1"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences

info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set

info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole

info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator

info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid f5de3fd5ccded92e40e86c652ce2a6f9414ee1a2

info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id f5de3fd5ccded92e40e86c652ce2a6f9414ee1a2 --bundle com.vr.iphone.sample

info: [debug] App is not installed. Will try to install the app.

info: [debug] Installing app using cmd: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id f5de3fd5ccded92e40e86c652ce2a6f9414ee1a2 --bundle "/Users/al/work/sample.app

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Unable to install [/Users/al/work/sample.app] to device with id [f5de3fd5ccded92e40e86c652ce2a6f9414ee1a2]. Error [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id f5de3fd5ccded92e40e86c652ce2a6f9414ee1a2 --bundle "/Users/al/work/sample.app"
Assertion failed: (AMDeviceStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.afc"), &afcFd, NULL) == 0), function handle_device, file fruitstrap.c, line 523.
]
```

Comment: Following the log, appium can't install the app. Did you try to install this app manually?

Comment: @Eugene, The app  get installed already in physical device by manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Appium to install your app on your device, Just uninstall your App manually and in setUp code use absolute path of .apk file like this:

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.1.1");

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Name");

File appDir = new File("/home/filename/ProjectFile");

File app = new File(appDir, "appname.apk");

capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());

It will install your app on your device.

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried to launch on real device, but your logs saying you tried to launch on simulator.

If you are using UI version of appium, Please uncheck Force Device option in appium and give UDID of real device which you connected in appium and prelaunch. your app will be installed.